# Connect an existing NBL with Nginx-controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Please, Is it possible to create an NLB with terraform and connect this NLB with Nginx-controller during its installation with helm chart ? I would separate the creation of the load balancer and the Ngix-controller.

Comment: as far I know you can't do that. when you set your service type to LoadBalancer, it will provision a load balancer(NLB) for you. why do you need to separate your NLB from the rest of your nginx deployment?

Comment: @RezaNasiri  Thank you for your response. For any raison, if I would re-install/update my Nginx contoller, I would keeping my NLB and not destroy it.

Comment: NLB is associated with k8s service so as long as your service object doesn't get deleted, you can use the same NLB while upgrading the controller